# What's the max size of JSON file output by fs.writeFileSync in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, size, maxlength

On handling 10e6+ records market data by JSON, when I try to write them to a single JSON file and use some simple tools like [npm json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to serve locally, it seems that I have faced the maximum of JSON output.

After some try, here are the test result

```
// item format
// {"time":1357542000,"close":13.59,"high":13.59,"low":13.59,"open":13.59,"volumefrom":0,"volumeto":0}

// import from .json
// OK: Read: No: 0.18M, Size: 20MB, 
// NG: Read: No: 0.2M, Size: 23MB, 

// fs.readFileSync
// OK: Read: No: 3.85M, Size: 441MB, 
// NG: Read: No: 3.9M, Size: 447MB, 

// fs.writeFileSync
// OK: Write: No: 4.05M, Size: 464MB, 
// NG: Write: No: 4.1M, Size: 0, 

// fs.writeFileSync with item empty
// OK: Write: No: 40M, Size: 195MB, 
// NG: Write: No: 42M, Size: 0,
```

I'm quite confused since the limit changes by Number of records and Size of JSON file and it's just not a constant. Is there anyone who knows the deep reason of it?

```
import fs from 'fs';
// writeFileSync
fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, JSON.stringify(outputData));
// readFileSync
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(outputPath, 'utf8'));
```

Tested by running typescript in VS code using [vscode-ts-node-debugging](https://github.com/Enterprise-JS/vscode-ts-node-debugging)